# Sparse matrix factorization of a rank deficient matrix by decomposition into linearly independent components

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, rank

I've got a little conjecture I need to prove for a theoretical result related to causal Bayes net search with latent variables under sparsity constraints.  If you're interested in the application please feel free to email me at adambrod@andrew.cmu.edu.

Here's the problem:

Suppose we have a $p\times q$ real matrix $A$ such that 1) $A$ is rank deficient so $\textrm{rk}(A)=r<\min(p,q)$, and 2) there are no zero elements in $A$.

I want to prove that there is no factorization of $A$ into two matrices with
fewer total non-zero elements than some factorization of $A$ into two
matrices $B$ and $C$ of dimensions $p\times r$ and $r\times q$.

The proof strategy I'm employing is proof by induction on rank.

The base case, $\textrm{rk}(A)=1$ is trivial ($B$ and $C$ must have at least $p+q$ non-zero
elements between the two of them in order for every element of $A$ to be
non-zero and that is the maximum number of elements in a pair of matrices
with dimensions $p\times r$ and $r\times q$).

The induction step is as follows:  Subtract a matrix $D$ of rank 1 from $A$
such that the resulting matrix $S$ is of rank $r-1$.  This corresponds to
removing all of the "influence" of some specific row vector $v$ from $A$,
such that $v$ is linearly independent of the remainder, $S$.  $D$ can be expressed
as the outer product of some column vector $w$ with $v$.  Suppose $wv$ is the
sparsest factorization of $D$ (the possibility of this is implied by our
base case).  Let $RT$ be the sparsest factorization of $S$ of dimensions $p\times 
r-1$ and $r-1\times q$ respectively.  My conjecture is that the sparsest
factorization of $A$ is achieved by appending these two sparsest
factorizations, that is, the sparsest factorization of $A$ is the product of
$R$ with $w$ appended as the $r$th column and $T$ with $v$ appended as the $r$th row.
Because $D$ and $S$ are linearly independent this seems quite plausible, but a
rigorous demonstration eludes me.

Any solutions, suggestions, or references would be greatly appreciated, and of course, if you provide me with personal information (name/department affiliation), I would be happy to acknowledge your assistance in any publications I apply this result in.

Thanks!